# Как вычислить сумму ряда?

Tags: c++, математика, циклы, for, ряды

[image: задача]

Дано натуральное `n`, действительное `a`.

Как вычислить сумму?

Comment: Оператор + вас чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: эх, думал будет code golf, а тут с++ тег :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С ностальгией (и тоской) вспоминаются времена, когда программирование было по сути разделом математики...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
double sum(double a, int n)
{
    if (a != 1.0)
    {
        double an = pow(a,n), a1 = a - 1.0;

        return (a*a*(an-1.0)-n*a1)/(an*a1*a1);
    }
    else
    {
        return n*(n+3)/2.0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double a;
    int n;
    cin >> a >> n;
    cout << sum(a,n) << endl;
}
```

Тот редкий случай, когда я использовал столь нелюбимую мною `pow` :)

Тут оба решения - правильное и с помощью цикла :) - https://ideone.com/iWpwFZ

Comment: Это хорошо, это плюс...)))